# Controlling <span> tag inside a <div> tag using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The following code works fine (copied from the w3schools.com)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("span").hide();
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("span").show();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>

<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>

</body>
</html>
```

But if I enclose the following code into a `<div>` tag and change the `<p>` into `<span>` it doesn't work then.

```
<body>
<div>
  <span>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</span>

  <button id="hide">Hide</button>
  <button id="show">Show</button>
</div>
</body>
```

I want to do similar sort of work, having span inside a div, and if I enter a wrong entry for example age less than 5, it should display a `<span>` tag saying sorry, this service isn't for the under 5 years. Means i want to control a span tag  inside a div tag, whereas a `<p>` works fine inside a div tag its only span i noticed at the min (maybe more tags).

Comment: You're closing your span tag with a p tag... Why would it work? Close your span tag with it's proper closing tag not some other closing tag

Comment: Where are you closing the first `<span>` and where  `</p>` comes?

Comment: 1. Where is the div 2. close the span tag 3.remove </p>

Comment: I see a grand total of zero divs in your code

Comment: Thanks every one, What I want is to control a span tag inside a div tag using Jquery. I have made my question clear now. Sorry for the mess-up with the initial question. It's just a FRIDAY. Thanks!

Comment: That's a better example. Just target span instead of p man

Comment: you changed your `p` to a `span` in your html - you need to reflect that in your js too and that will fix your issue

Comment: Apologies! BUT the problem isn't missing something tags or etc. Apparently i can't control a span tag inside a div tag.

Comment: @zaffar Give your div a class like <div class="someclass"> then use $(".someclass span") . I also mention that in my answer

Comment: As of the current edit of the question, the first example *won't* work (because it's trying to hide a `span` that doesn't exist in the document).  The second example *will* work, given the same javascript.   The enclosing `div` will make no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In General just "span" or even "div span" would work. **BUT** if you need to reach specific span inside a div you have to give the div or span a class then reach the span. see the snippet below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $(".someclass .wehide").hide();
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $(".someclass .wehide").show();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="someclass">
  <span class="wehide">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</span>
<br/>
  <span class="wedont">If you click on the "Hide" button, I WILL NOT disappear.</span>
  <button id="hide">Hide</button>
  <button id="show">Show</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Evik Ghazarian. I had only changed the body of the html, and meant to reflect accordingly into the jquery, which however i have changed. The question is how this code gonna work? Means how you can control a span inside a div? Thanks again!

Comment: Many thanks! Let's say we have more than one span tag and i just want to disappear one. How do I access the one span tag only; <span>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</span> I know we can give id to the span but question is what would be the code then $(".someclass span").hide(); instead of ".someclass span" ? "

Comment: then give span a class also

Comment: @zaffar see the update i made 2 spans different class

Comment: @zaffar if the answer helped please verify as answer. Remember if using class for both div and span it should be something like ".someclass .wehide"

Comment: Many thanks and your code works perfectly fine. I really appreciate it, just another query, what if I enclose everything within the body tag in a form tag, e.g. <body> <form action="" id=""> then the rest of the above code you mentioned then </form> and then </body>. Soon I enclose it within a form, it doesn't work otherwise it works. Could you please give any thought on it? Although your answer still stand perfect! Many thanks

Comment: if I enclose everything within the body tag in a form tag, e.g. <body> <form action="" id=""> then the rest of the above code you mentioned then </form> and then </body>. Soon I enclose it within a form, it doesn't work otherwise it works. Please can you help with this as well?

Comment: are you using # for id? if its <form id="someid"> , you have to use #someid or maybe give it a class like <form id="someid" class="someclass"> and use .someclass

Answer (score 0):

It should work

```
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#hide").click(function(){
                $("div span").hide();
              });
              $("#show").click(function(){
                $("div span").show();
              });
            });
            </script>

            <body>
                <div>
                    <span>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</span>   
                </div>

                <button id="hide">Hide</button>
                <button id="show">Show</button>

            </body>
```

But a better aproach should be using selector like

```
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#hide").click(function(){
                $(".myspan").hide();
              });
              $("#show").click(function(){
                $(".myspan").show();
              });
            });
            </script>

            <body>
                <div>
                    <span class="myspan">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</span>    
                </div>

                <button id="hide">Hide</button>
                <button id="show">Show</button>
            </body>
```

But if for some reason you can't add class selector use some parent reference

```
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#hide").click(function(){
                $(".myparent span").hide();
              });
              $("#show").click(function(){
                $(".myparent span").show();
              });
            });
            </script>

            <body>
                <div class="myparent">
                    <span >If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</span>  
                </div>

                <button id="hide">Hide</button>
                <button id="show">Show</button>
            </body>
```

According to your needs, you can do something like

```
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#hide").click(function(){
                $(".erros").hide();
              });
              $("#show").click(function(){
                $(".erros").show();
              });
            });
            </script>

            <body>
                <div class="form">
                    <div>
                        Other content like input
                    </div>
                    <div class="erros">
                        <span >this service isn't for the under 5 years. </span>    
                    </div>
                </div>

                <button id="hide">Hide</button>
                <button id="show">Show</button>
            </body>
```